# Is it better to cache infrequently changing 'dictionary' tables and best practices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, associations

In a Rails app, say I have the following models:

```
class Movies < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movie_genres
  has_many :genres, through: :movie_genres
end

class Genres < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movie_genres
  has_many :movies, through: :movie_genres
end

class MovieGenre < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movies
  belongs_to :genres
end
```

The genres table is nothing more than `id` and `label` fields. Between the many app views and biz logic methods, I'm going to need to lookup the `id` for a given genre very frequently, but the actual data is going to change extremely infrequently.

Does it make sense to only do the database call once at app load and store into memory a hash with the info?

If yes, what's a good practice for this?  Class variable in `Genre`?  Set global  variable in an initializer?  I realize that I will need to setup a hook to rebuild this memory store if there's a transaction on the `genres` table.

This question is being asked with scaling in mind where `genres` is only one of many lookup-style db tables with infrequently changing data but high frequency lookups.

Comment: You're asking about cache invalidation, one of the only two hard problems in computer science :)

Answer (score 1):

While memcache-backed cache (as suggested in @Md.FarhanMemon's answer) is a good-enough answer for most situations, semi-static frequently-accessed dictionaries might warrant in-process caching (no remote calls = no overhead, such as network latency).

There are a few ways you can implement it (global vars, class vars, class instance vars, maybe something else). It's an implementation detail, though. What matters is that data is stored in the app server's memory.

With a few lines of code you can implement timeouts and everything. Then the only major drawback is inability to reliably/consistenly update cache across multiple processes. But if your app can handle slightly stale dictionary for a minute (let's suppose you refresh in-process cache every minute), then it's a cheap price to pay for ultra-fast cache access.

Source: I have successfully used this type of caching in a quite loaded app of mine (about 65M hits/day). Your mileage may vary.

Comment: When you say this type of use case "might warrant in-process caching", do you mean because that solution is simpler and comes with no potential memcache server fees? Any other pros?

Comment: @Codosapien: memcache access incurs network overhead. Even a few milliseconds may matter, if it is really high-read data.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are not at all recommended, good practice is to use `rails caching` which is best in such scenarios. You can set `expiry time` of cache as per convenience and if you need to update cache when new `row` is added, you can just run an `after_save` callback and set the updated cache like

```
Rails.cache.write(key, value, options)
```

if not that there are multiple options like `view caching` or `action caching` as per your requirement..

Memcachier is one good caching server provided as heroku addon if you use heroku.

Read about [Rails Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html) in more detail to understand its feasibility and solution to your concern..